# Two dozens or two dozen

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, nouns

Is there any slight difference between these two?

1. *She bought two dozens of eggs.*
2. *She bought two dozen eggs.*

In an online course a tutor told that second one is more appropriate if both options come in exam.

They both appear same to me.

Comment: The second is what people say in real life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conventionally, words that stand for specific amounts do not take the plural form when used with numbers: two dozen (dozen meaning 12 in this case), two million (not two millions).

However, if the number is unspecified, then the plural can be used.

There were ***dozens*** of people at the party (an estimate more than 12 but likely less than 100 or so).